# Can I lock (or make uneditable) portions of a word document?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I am looking to make a letterhead for my company.  Right now I currently have an image within the header of the document and an image within the footer of the document.

Is there any way I can lock these portions of the page so that other users cannot edit the header or footer?

Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Can't take credit for this but I found this forum post from user "Mike" at http://help.wugnet.com/office/lock-header-MS-Word-ftopict1151220.html

- Display the Developer Tab on the ribbon. (Open word options, then click
  the check-box in the Popular section.)
- With your template open, navigate to the Developer tab.
- Click the Protect Document button. (You should see a sidebar.)
- Under Editing Restrictions, click "Allow only this type of editing in the
  document" and set the dropdown to "No changes (Read only)"
- Click somewhere in your template that isn't the header/footer and hold
  Ctrl-A to select all.
- Under the Exceptions part of the sidebar now displayed in Editing
  restrictions, click the check-box for 'Everyone'. In other words, your
  entire document is read-only except for the main part in the middle, which
  can be edited by everyone.
- Click the "Yes, Start Enforcing Protection" button, and set a password if
  you want to.

This does exactly what I want it to.  Thanks Mike.

Answer (score 3):

It is called content control. In Word 2007 the easiest way to do what you want is to click on the Review tab in the ribbon, then click the Protect Document button and select "Restrict Formatting and Editing". Make the changes you want in the side bar that appears.